# Inconsistent .loc behavior

Tags: pandas

If we have the following df.

```
d = {'A': {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 3},
 'B': {0: 2, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 2, 5: 1},
 'C': {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  2  0
1  2  0  2
2  2  0  3
3  2  0  0
4  3  2  1
5  3  1  0
```

If we wanted to set index 3,4,5 to certain values the following does not work.

```
df.loc[[3,4,5]] = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])

Output:
   A  B  C
0  0  2  0
1  2  0  2
2  2  0  3
3  4  5  6
4  4  5  6
5  4  5  6
```

The below also returns the same output as not slicing the columns:

```
df.loc[[3,4,5],'A':'C'] = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

However, putting the column in a list returns the expected output.

```
df.loc[[3,4,5],['A','B','C']] = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])

   A  B  C
0  0  2  0
1  2  0  2
2  2  0  3
3  4  4  4
4  5  5  5
5  6  6  6
```

Why do the columns need to be in a list for the series to align on index?

Comment: `df.loc[[3,4,5], :]` also works. `[3,4,5]` are the row values and `:` are the column values.

Comment: Slicing the columns does not return the expected output either.

Comment: `df.loc[[3,4,5]] = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])` works on my system (pandas 1.1.3).

Comment: Can repro this in 1.3.3, 1.3.4 and 1.3.5. The behaviour seems to originate in `_align_series` [indexing.py L2066-L2068](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/de290f76815840549f273baa6ed7ba751dede871/pandas/core/indexing.py#L2066-L2068). Only when there are 2 sequence-based indexers is the series tiled and reshaped. Otherwise it's just reindexed and returned [indexing.py L2072-L2087](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/de290f76815840549f273baa6ed7ba751dede871/pandas/core/indexing.py#L2072-L2087)

Comment: Thank you for providing that information... the other interesting thing is that if you just use `df.loc[[3,4]]` you get a shape mismatch error. Seems like any three index labels passed will show the behavior in the question I asked, but if you only select 2, or 4 index labels for example, it gives a shape mismatch error